# Loopback: How to define ACL rules in a mixin?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I want to define a set of ACL rules that should be easily portable and extendable by using mixins.

Defining these in the `MyModel.json` for some model MyModel is trivial:

```
"acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    }]
```

This works, and correctly blocks API calls for everyone. However, when I do the same thing (or so I think) in a mixin, it does not work:

```
module.exports = function (Model, options) {

  Model.getApp(function (err, app) {

    app.models.ACL.create({
      model: Model.modelName,
      accessType: '*',
      principalType: 'ROLE',
      principalId: '$everyone',
      permission: 'DENY'
    }, function (err, acl) {
      console.log('ACL entry created: %j', acl);
    });

  });

};
```

What is missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After going through the sources to see how Loopback itself registers ACL at config time, the following appears to be the correct way of doing this in a mixin:

```
module.exports = function (Model, options) {

  Model.settings.acls.push({
    "accessType": "*",
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$everyone",
    "permission": "DENY"
  });

};
```